# Problem about tensors and vector subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, tensors, multilinear-algebra

Given a vector space $V$ and its dual $V^*$, we say $\alpha \in T^r(V^*)$ is an *elementary* tensor if there exist $\tilde{v}^1 , \dots, \tilde{v}^r  \in V^*$ such that:

$$\alpha = \tilde{v}^1 \wedge \dots \wedge \tilde{v}^r .$$

If $\alpha \neq 0$, we can show that $W_\alpha = \{x \in V : \tilde{v}^j(x) = 0, j = 1, \dots , r \}$ is a subspace of $V$.

However, how do we show that:

1) $W_\alpha$ the subspace depends only on $\alpha$ and not the representation above as an elementary tensor? I'm not sure how to do this one. Should I do so by contradiction? ie assume $\alpha$ has two elementary tensor representations with only one of them generating $W_\alpha$ and then show this is a contradiction, making this a problem about uniqueness of elementary tensor representation?

2) $W_\alpha = W_\beta \iff \exists c \neq 0$ such that $\alpha = c\beta$. 
The $\implies$ direction is where I'm having issues i.e., the direction where we assume $W_\alpha = W_\beta$. I was considering a proof by contradiction where I induct on $r$.

Comment: Just a couple of facts, that at least should help when $V$ is finite-dimensional: 1) Two sets of vectors generate the same $\alpha$ up to a multiplicative constant iff they span the same subspace, 2) If $V= V^\star$ (e.g. when $V$ is finite-dimensional) then $W_\alpha$ is the space orthogonal to the span of the vectors.

Comment: If we set $V_\alpha = \mathrm{span} \{ \tilde v^1, \ldots, \tilde v^r \}$ then $W_\alpha = \{ x \in V \, : \, v(x) = 0 \, \forall v \in V_\alpha \}$.